# Arxiv: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: arxiv

I'm uploading my PdfLaTeX submission on ArXiv and I'm getting an error, I tried to include a `00README.XXX` file with nostamp but it didn't work. I also don't see anything wrong with the citations in line 50, so I don't understand the problem, and am not sure how to fix it.

> arXiv now processes new submissions and replacements with TeX Live 2016.
> Reprocess
>
> arXiv's automated TeX processing has failed to process your source. The 3 most common mistakes causing this are:
>
> 1. File-name upper/lower-case mismatch between TeX source and figure or included files
> 2. Missing customized or differing version of style files. The most common being natbib.sty with the "Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations" (for the fix see #1 in texlive faq)
> 3. Missing, misnamed, or non-portable complete paths to figure files
>
> The TeX Log appears below, and is best read bottom up, to see the relevant error message from your source processing within the appropriate section. If your problem is not solved by making the corrections as illustrated above, or your problem is extremely complex in nature, please contact us citing submit/3322513 to ensure a more rapid response. Please note that it may take a day or two to receive a personal response.
>
> You may wish to hit "Ctrl + F" ("Apple + F" on a Mac) or browse to Edit and select "Find" to search for "error". Please note that the first error may simply be arXiv's application of hypertex failing.

TeX log appears below:

```
[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2016 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <Suturing_labeled_mini3.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S011-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <ieeecolor.cls> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <S019-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S020.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S005-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S009.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S017.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S002.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S016-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S008-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S008.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S011.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S002-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S004.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S014-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S005.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S015.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S004-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <overview.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <architecture.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S006-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S018.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S016.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <LOGO-tmi-web.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S001-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S009-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S003-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <LOGO-tmi-web-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S010-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S014.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S003.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S001.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <tmi.tex> is of type 'PDFLATEX'.
[verbose]: <S012-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <Suturing_labeled_mini4.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S006.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S017-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S007.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <Suturing_labeled_mini.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S012.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <fig1.png> is of type 'Image (gif/jpg etc)'.
[verbose]: <S020-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S007-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <tmi.sty> is of type 'TeX auxiliary'.
[verbose]: <tmi.synctex> is of type 'unknown'.
[verbose]: <S019.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S010.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: <S015-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S018-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S013-eps-converted-to.pdf> is of type 'PDF'.
[verbose]: <S013.eps> is of type 'Postscript'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'tmi.tex'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3322513/ && pdflatex 'tmi.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmi.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./ieeecolor.cls

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `ieeecolor',
but the document class provides `IEEEtran'.

Document Class: IEEEtran 2002/11/18 revision V1.6b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- The source comments contain changelog notes.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
-- This is a 10 point document.
) (./tmi.sty) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithmic.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty

Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition
of \endfigure, most likely
\let\endfigure=\end@float
which has now been changed to
\def\endfigure{\end@float}
because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float
(like done by several packages changing float behaviour)
can't take effect on \endfigure.
Please complain to your document class author.


Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition
of \endtable, most likely
\let\endtable=\end@float
which has now been changed to
\def\endtable{\end@float}
because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float
(like done by several packages changing float behaviour)
can't take effect on \endtable.
Please complain to your document class author.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

)) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
No file tmi.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)
<overview.pdf, id=4, 926.50137pt x 305.7021pt> <use overview.pdf>
Overfull \hbox (4.34377pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 44--45
[][]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Kim2014' on page 1 undefined on input line 45.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Kim2014' on page 1 undefined on input line 45.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Sarikaya2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Mitchell2019' on page 1 undefined on input line 51.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Dai2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 51.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Dai2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 51.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Sabour2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 51.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Bouget2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 51.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `LOGO-tmi-web.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.52

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.52

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tmi.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'tmi.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'tmi.out' (1597349645 >= 1597349644)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'tmi.aux' (1597349645 >= 1597349644)
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3322513/ && pdflatex 'tmi.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmi.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(./ieeecolor.cls

LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `ieeecolor',
but the document class provides `IEEEtran'.

Document Class: IEEEtran 2002/11/18 revision V1.6b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- The source comments contain changelog notes.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
-- This is a 10 point document.
) (./tmi.sty) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithmic.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty

Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition
of \endfigure, most likely
\let\endfigure=\end@float
which has now been changed to
\def\endfigure{\end@float}
because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float
(like done by several packages changing float behaviour)
can't take effect on \endfigure.
Please complain to your document class author.


Package subfig Warning: Your document class has a bad definition
of \endtable, most likely
\let\endtable=\end@float
which has now been changed to
\def\endtable{\end@float}
because otherwise subsequent changes to \end@float
(like done by several packages changing float behaviour)
can't take effect on \endtable.
Please complain to your document class author.

(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption) usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

))
No file tmi.aux.
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-config/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)
<overview.pdf, id=1, 926.50137pt x 305.7021pt> <use overview.pdf>
Overfull \hbox (4.34377pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 43--44
[][]

LaTeX Warning: Citation `Kim2014' on page 1 undefined on input line 44.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Kim2014' on page 1 undefined on input line 44.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Sarikaya2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 48.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Mitchell2019' on page 1 undefined on input line 50.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Dai2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 50.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Dai2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 50.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Sabour2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 50.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `Bouget2017' on page 1 undefined on input line 50.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `LOGO-tmi-web.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.51

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.51

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tmi.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'tmi.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'tmi.aux' (1597349645 >= 1597349645)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3322513/ && tex 'tmi.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./tmi.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tmi.log.

[verbose]: tex 'tmi.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3322513/ && tex 'tmi.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./tmi.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tmi.log.

[verbose]: tex 'tmi.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'tmi.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: well the first fatal error is "LOGO-tmi-web.pdf is missing". So add the logo to the upload.

Comment: Oh hey thank you! It seems all my pdf converted from eps put "-eps-converted-to" at the end of the file names, so I didn't notice this. I changed names of all pdf converted from eps and it worked!